# ssh port forwarding through pseudo terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, osx, mysql

Here's a situation:

I do all my work on a Mac.

> 1. There's a certain linux server '*server01*' that provides access to
>      another linux server '*server02*' via a pseudo terminal
>
>    So, to ssh into '*server02*', I do this from my mac:
>
>    ```
>    ssh -t server01 'inline server02'
>    ```
> 2. Then it asks me for a password to '*server01*'; I enter it and that
>      logs me into '*server02*'. Now, I am on the '*server02*' terminal.
> 3. From '*server02*' I can access the mysql database that is sitting on
>      '*server03*' using the following mysql command:
>
>    ```
>    mysql --host=server03 --port=4201 --user=myuser --password=mypass mydb
>    ```
> 4. Neither '*server01*' nor '*server02*' nor my mac have SSH access to '*server03*'

Now, I want to access the mysql on '*server03*' from my mac directly through some kind of port forwarding. So, if I type the below command on my mac terminal, it should connect me to the mysql database on '*server03*':

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=4201 --user=myuser --password=mypass mydb
```

Is there a way to do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `inline` command on server01 do to get to server02?

Answer (score 1):

If you can ssh to server02 from the server01 you could try

```
ssh -t -L server02:4201 server01 'ssh -N -L server03:4201 server02'
```

it will chain connection

localhost:4201 -> server02:4201 -> server03:4201

just connects locally to port *4201* on the mac

Better use key authentication and ssh-agent to avoid typing passwords.